# Seemingly easy probability that can't be solved using multiplication.

Tags: probability

There are 15 colored beads; 7 are red, 3 are blue and 5 are green. Three beads are selected at random and replaced. Find the probability that one is red, one blue and one green. The answer is 14/75.

I can't seem to solve this seemingly easy problem, pulling my hairs out for trying this goddamn problem for 3 hours please anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1...what is the probability of red followed by blue followed by green?

Hint 2...how many arrangements of the colours are there?

Answer (score 1):

I fear that the answer you have may be wrong
Or maybe I made a mistake

You can think as David Quinn suggested, or a slightly different way:

> Favourable Cases / Total Cases

1. The total cases are often easier to calculate: how to extract 3 object (you can think simultaneously) from a set of 15? This is a very classic formula
2. Favourable cases are easy as well: how many ways to get 1 red from a set of 7, 1 green from a set of 3, 1 blue from a set of 5? This is even easier

At the end, anyway, I (and I think with David’s method as well) get $ \frac{3}{13}$ and maybe you have already found this number a lot of times!

Comment: From what I understand since 3 beads can be chosen in 6 orders or permutations we multiply 6 with 7/15*5/15*3/15, what do you think @giolendius?

Comment: If you follow Quinn ‘s idea, you multiply by $3!$.   My procedure, which turns out the same, is to consider, on total cases “extraction” of 3 object from a set of 15. This is the Binomial formula, which has again a $3!$ factor

Comment: I think your formula works only when we have the same type of objects like a set of black balls or something and not when there are a few black balls and a dozen red balls, etc in a set. Am I correct?

Comment: On the denominator, I.e. the total cases, you want all possible combination of 3 thing from 15, and you are actually don’t caring about the color. You can think each bead has a name (A,B, C....) and you take 3 (not caring about order, hence the binomial. No color at all.         Instead, on the numerator, you split at the beginning the colours: how many ways to take a red ball (the beat B from one of RedBeat=\{A,B,...,G\}? Again binomial of $\Bin{7,1}$ which it’s easily 7 this time. Then you multiply for each color